# How many levels in a dataframe index?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to know how many levels there are in a dataframe, without knowing if that dataframe has a Multi-index or a 'Normal' index.

Assuming a dataframe `df`, and a variable `nb_levels` to hold the result, i can do the following if the dataframe has a multi-index :

```
>>> nb_levels = len(df.index[0])    
nb_levels = 2
```

*assuming a 2-levels multi-index*

So i could get my desired result like this :

```
try:
    df.index.get_level_values(1)
    nb_levels = 1
except:
    nb_levels = len(df.index[0])
```

But it feels like a horrible hack, and surely there must be simple way to get this result. Problem is that i can't seem to find it. Help ?

Comment: If `df.index.get_level_values(1)` doesnt fail it only means that levels exists, it doesnt say anything about the amount of levels present in the `df`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Each Dataframe has an attribute holding the amount of levels:

```
nblevels = df.index.nlevels
```